# how to arrange the parameter in a new promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I just learned about promises and async/await.
I want my function to wait for some function inside to finish before proceeding. 
Basically, I guess it should look something like this:

```js
async function doSomething(data){
//some code
await createMarkup(data)
//do some stuff which must wait for createMarkup to finish
}

function createMarkup(input){
return new Promise ((???) => {
//some code
resolve(markup)
})
}
```

Now, in most of the tutorials I read about promises and stuff, the parameter of the "new Promise" was always "(resolve, reject)". This has been the case so often that I wondered whether this is some necessity?

In my case, the promise shall take exactly one argument. So can I just, like in any other parameter, put my one argument into the parameter and thats it? Or do I have to take care of somethign?^^

Comment: Have you read the [documentation on Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)? `resolve` and `reject` are the functions, provided as arguments, for your Promise callback to use. You couldn’t use `resolve(markup)` without defining `resolve` in the parameter list.

Comment: The *callback function* that you give to `new Promise` will always receive *two arguments*, one function you call to resolve the promise and a second to reject it. A promise doesn't take or provide any other arguments. I'm a bit unclear what single argument exactly you want to "put" where.

Answer (score 3):

> In my case, the promise shall take exactly one argument.

Promise will take one argument. That argument will be the function you want it to run. This is how `Promise` is defined. It is not something under your control.

The function you pass to the promise will receive two arguments. It is passed them when it is called, which is done by the Promise library (which is not code you wrote, and follows the specification for Promises, so it is not something under your control). It is traditional to call them `resolve` and `reject`, but you can call them whatever you like. The function you pass needs to call `resolve(any_data)` if it succeeds and `reject(any_data)` if it fails. If you don't intend to call `reject`, then you don't need to mention it in the argument list, the second argument will be passed to the function though.

You can create a function which returns a promise (like `createMarkup` in your example), which takes any arguments you like and makes them available to the function you pass to `Promise` via closures.

Comment: Note that it's entirely possible to do something like `new Promise(resolve => ...)` if you don't need `reject`, but that is somewhat tangential.

Comment: What do you mean by "closures"? Could you elaborate how this would look like with, lets say a number of 5 arguments?

Comment: `function createMarkup(one, two, three, four, five){`